# Regex to exclude trailing zero with even numbers of digits

Tags: java, regex

I need some support on a regex I am trying to write.

I received a string which is always made of 8 digits (like 12345678). From this string, I need to remove trailing zeros but always keeping an even number of digits.

So for example:

- 12345678 --> 12345678
- 12345600 --> 123456
- 12345000 --> 123450
- 12003000 --> 120030

The though part for me is to make sure to keep the even numbers.

I tried using some `(\d\d)+[^(00)]+` but it does not achieve what I want.

Comment: "I tried using some `(\d\d)+[^(00)]+` but it does not achieve what I want." You're a 34k-rep user: come on, you know that you should provide a [mcve], showing what you have tried in a way we can run, showing the inputs, expected and actual outputs.

Comment: What if the string is `00000000`? Should it become empty or `0`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew from the business case we will not have this value but technically I would expect it returns an empty string

Comment: @AndyTurner indeed I could add the link to the regex https://regex101.com/r/gwyA0z/1

Comment: The `(?:00)+$`  only works here because your numbers are all even. `replaceAll("^((?:\\d\\d)*?)0+$", "$1")` might be a better bet for other cases. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUQx1f/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct but in my business case all numbers we receive are even number of digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple regex like this should work:

```
(?:00)+$
```

replace with empty string.

I used a non-capturing group instead of character class to group 2 zeros together, and then added a `+` quantifier to only match "multiples" of 2 zeros i.e. an even number of zeros.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RG0xqM/1)

If you want a regex that can match instead of replace, this works:

```
^\d+?0?(?=(?:00)*$)
```

Lazily looking for digits until we reach a 0. Do we match this zero or not? That depends on whether we see an even number of 0s after it. This however does not work with the case of all 0s, like `0000`, but since you said that you will never encounter this value,  you don't need to worry too much.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RG0xqM/2)

Answer (score 5):

Try this regex:

```
(?:00)*$
```

Replace each match with a blank string.

**[click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/C55Sot/2)**

**Explanation:**

- `(?:00)*` - matches 0 or more occurrences of `00`.
- `$` - asserts the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "(00)*$";
final String string = "12345678\n"
     + "12400000\n"
     + "12005600\n"
     + "12340000\n"
     + "12000000\n"
     + "12340000\n"
     + "12345000";
final String subst = "";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```

Below is the result

```
Substitution result: 12345678
1240
120056
1234
12
1234
123450
```